# First Chern class of torsion sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, chern-classes, torsion

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, $\mathscr T$ a torsion sheaf with irreducible support of codimension $1$, say $Z$. Then the first Chern class $c_1(\mathscr T)$ is of form $r[Z]$. Is there anything we can say about the positivity of $r$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coefficient $r$ is equal to the length of $\mathcal{T}$ at the generic point of $Z$, so it is positive.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you have a good reference of this?

Comment: I am sure you can find this in Fulton's "Intersection Theory".